# Get list of all values in a key:value list

Tags: json, bash

So my input looks like

```
{"selling":"0","quantity":"2","price":"80000","date":"1401384212","rs_name":"overhault","contact":"PM","notes":""}

{"selling":"0","quantity":"100","price":"80000","date":"1401383271","rs_name":"sammvarnish","contact":"PM","notes":"Seers Bank W321 :)"}

{"selling":"0","quantity":"100","price":"70000","date":"1401383168","rs_name":"pwnoramaa","contact":"PM","notes":""}
```

and the output I want must look like

```
0,2,80000,1401384212,overhault,PM,""

0,100,80000,1401383271,sammvarnish,PM,"Seers Bank W321 :)"

0,100,70000,1401383168,pwnoramaa,PM,""
```

What's the best way to do this in bash?

EDIT: changed my needs. 
The new output I want is, for 
{"selling":"0","quantity":"2","price":"80000","date":"1401384212","rs_name":"overhault","contact":"PM","notes":"testnote"}
as input,

```
rs name: \t overhault
quantity: \t 2
price: \t 80000
date: \t 29-05 19:23
contact: \t PM
notes: \t testnote
```

Where \t is a tab character (like in echo "\t").
As you can see, this one is a tad bit more complicated. 
For example, it changes the order, and requires the UNIX timestamp to be converted to an alternative format.

I'll use any tool you can offer me as long as you explain clearly how I can use it from a bash script. The input will consist of three of such lines, delimited by a newline character, and it must print the output with an empty line between each of the results.

Comment: This probably doesn't work in bash, but some quick playing around: [`(?:\{|\G,)\K"[^"]+":"([^"]*)"`](http://regex101.com/r/fB0hR8)

Comment: is that answers in sed or awk would be welcomed?

Comment: Very ugly:: `awk -F '","|":"|"}' '{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\"%s\"\n",$2,$4,$6,$8,$10,$12,$14}'` and also this regex:: `(?<=:")(.*?)(?="(?:,|}))`

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this with regular expressions/bash, there are JSON parsers for this kind of task. Simple Python example:

```
import json
data = json.loads('{"selling":"0","quantity":"2"}')
data = ','.join(data.values())
print(data)
```

I strongly suggest you just use a simple script like this which you make executable and then call.

EDIT: here's a version which preserves the order:

```
 import json
 data = json.loads('{"selling":"0","quantity":"2", "price":"80000"}')
 orderedkeys = ['selling', 'quantity', 'price']
 values = [data[key] for key in orderedkeys]
 values = ','.join(values)
 print(values)
```

output:

```
 0,2,80000
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not output the values in the desired order. By the way, it would be a lot more readable if you used `'` or `"""` to surround the json string rather than escaping all the internal quotes.

Comment: Although the user requested a specific order, it's not clear that it's a reasonable request. If the input really is JSON, there's no particular reason the key/value pairs should be in that particular order.

Comment: This won't do, sorry. The input is only json because of the API that I'm getting the data from. The key/value pairs will always be in the same order.
I don't want to add any more dependencies to this script (this particular thing is part of a bigger script). I also don't know python, and I refuse to work in a language which I don't know.

Comment: @user3688448 if the keys are always the same and always in the same order, you can hardcode the order to get your desired output. I added an example to my post.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `t = operator.itemgetter('selling', 'quantity', 'price')` to produce the tuples. Then you can use `values = ','.join(t(data))`.

Comment: @timgeb
That was not my biggest concert. I just don't want python to be a dependency of my little script. Also, I don't know any python at all. I have no idea what that code does, so I'm not going to use it. It's simple enough, I can see that, but who knows when I might be in a situation where I'll have to debug it?

Comment: @user3688448 If you refuse to add to your toolbox you will end up using the wrong tools for a lot of tasks for the rest of your life. Regex/awk/sed might still work for this constrained example, but it is generally a bad idea to parse JSON with those tools and as soon as it gets a tad more complicated you'll be out of luck. Debugging a regex where a regex should not be used in the first place is far more painful than learning five lines of Python.

Comment: @timgeb
I know, I know.
But I don't use JSON often. Actually, this'll probably be the last time I'll be using it for a while. I'm just whipping up a quick script to do something.
Of course when I do a larger project that requires JSON I'll use another tool - I'm actually planning on learning python as soon as I get time for it. But right now, I just want this little script done, with the tools I know and can use. It might be just 5 lines now, but who knows when something goes wrong and I'll need Python knowledge to fix it?

Comment: @timgeb
Another thing is, how is this script gonna handle my input? This is part of a larger script which would normally get the JSON from a webpage, then store it into a variable. How would I get the data from that variable into this python script? Keep in mind that I don't know any python. Even if you were to present me how to do that, it'll only add potential to more bugs only someone who knows python could fix.

Comment: @user3688448 hmm, I'm sorry, I can't provide you with a regex that won't break easily when minor details in the input data change. Reading in the data from an URL is really easy with python. It would be a oneliner in your case, so I am going to provide it just in case you need it sometime in the future. data=json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read().decode('utf-8'))

Comment: @timgeb
Thanks for trying anyways. I'm pretty sure that my input won't really change much. I do know that a regex isn't the right way to do this, but I don't have much choices - I already wrote a part of a script that deals with part of this data. 
I spent way too much time on this today.